# How can I create clock auction with javascript from smart contracts?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle

i am pretty new for this area but I wanna create a dapp with auction function. is there any help how I can start that ? I start to create NFT marketplace but I am stuck now with this level, I can not get implementation from my smart contract to javascript.

this is my contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract SimpleAuction{
address payable public beneficiary;
uint public auctionEndTime;

address public highestBidder;
uint public highestBid;

mapping(address => uint) public pendingReturns;

bool ended = false;

event HighestBidIncrease(address bidder, uint amount);
event AuctionEnded(address winner, uint amount);

constructor(uint _biddingTime, address payable _beneficiary){
    beneficiary = _beneficiary;
    auctionEndTime = block.timestamp + _biddingTime;
}

function bid() public payable{
    if (block.timestamp > auctionEndTime){
        revert("The auction has already ended");
    }
    
    if (msg.value <= highestBid){
        revert("There is alreay a higher or equal bid");
    }
    
    if (highestBid != 0){
        pendingReturns[highestBidder] += highestBid;
    }
    
    highestBidder = msg.sender;
    highestBid = msg.value;
    emit HighestBidIncrease(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

function withdraw() public returns (bool){
    uint amount = pendingReturns[msg.sender];
    if(amount > 0){
        pendingReturns[msg.sender] = 0;
        
        if(!payable(msg.sender).send(amount)){
            pendingReturns[msg.sender] = amount;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function auctionEnd() public{
    if (block.timestamp < auctionEndTime){
        revert ("The auction has not ended yet");
    }
    
    if (ended){
        revert("the function auctionEnded has already been called");
    }
    
    ended = true;
    emit AuctionEnded(highestBidder, highestBid);
    
    beneficiary.transfer(highestBid);
}
```

}

Comment: you mean you want to utilize this contract and call its functions?. Are you working with truffle?

Comment: exactly , I work with truffle and I already created marketplace contract and it works fine , I deployed that with BSC testnet , there is no problem until now. only thing I need to add an auction function for my dapp.

Comment: So far so good. But to invoke the contract you need Web3.js. I don't know about the level of your familiarity with concepts like Contract ABI, address, bytecode etc. Then you also need to make a transaction and then send that transaction with an unlocked Account. It is not something I can provide in just one answer. You are going to need some exploring if you haven't created a transaction before. For example take a look at this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDo_MdyNJzI&t=1589s&ab_channel=DappUniversity

Answer (score 0):

i see that you took this code from the moralis auction tutorial,

1- this code is not useful for your marketplace as it is right now since this smart contracts starts the auction when the contract is DEPLOYED (which means when u run truffle migrate)

2- your smart contract needs 2 parameters to be deployed anyway which are the beneficiary address and the time of the auction, have you been able to deploy it correctly?? if not you have to add to your migrations this code :

```
const Auction = artifacts.require("Auction");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Auction,"120","0xF17A576C88EE43D30b67Eb412e2D588e2866102F");
};
```

where the 120 is the time in seconds and the address is the beneficiary address, ofc this is hardcoded for exemple purposes, you can input the values u like from certain variables

3- this smart contract is good for learning the logic of an auction but is useless for your actual project